# Osgi Equinox enable component from external bundle

Tags: osgi, bundle, equinox, declarative-services

Given this scenario:

Bundle A: component 1A (enabled:false)
Bundle B: component 2B

How can i enable component 1A from Bundle B or Component 2B?

I've tried to do it by using componentContext,

```
dsContext.enableComponent("1A");
```

but it seems to work only with services in the same bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Your using a mechanism that is intended for management and it seems you want to use it on application level. Declarative services should be enabled/disabled through their dependencies, or through a domain specific means. You should *not* let another actor that enables/disables a component. Using this route you likely get very complex systems since it is difficult to control the timing and order.

Technically, you should use the Apache Felix SCR Service to control the enable/disable of a DS, this is unfortunately not yet standardized and then requires Apache Felix SCR as implementation of DS.

If you explain why you want to enable/disable other components it might be possible to point you to better solutions.

Comment: Thanks your quick answer Peter. In fact, the real scenario is more complex. I'm trying to automate failover with OSGI equinox and zookeeper/exhibitor, so i can achieve several OSGIs running in High Availability.

I could rewrite the question... i need to stop/start bundles programmatically or maybe components, given that bundles using DS must be in START state to really serve services.

Comment: Actually Peter, both Equinox and Knopflerfish SCR implementations also implement the ScrService, as defined by Felix. So it's a _de facto_ standard already... it should really be in the spec!

Comment: Let me explain again the scenario: 
- Bundle SwitchOver has a zookeper/exhibitor and leader election recipe. When it becames leader it must "start" the bundle A, when it looses leadership, it must stop bundle A.
- Bundle A: it must be in START status since it provides and uses declarative services. This bundle has a bunch of components and one of them run the main code, so starting/stopping it really means doing something or not.

Given that, I've finally used a dummy component that let me start/stop the bundle A, since it's a mandatory reference for main component in bundle A...

Comment: When "switchoverbundle" is running, it can create or dispose this "dummy" component through a factory, in order to start/stop running things on Bundle A.

When i run in standalone mode (no need of high availability), and switchover bundle is not present (not running). The bundle A's Activator is responsible of creating this dummy component, by checking first that bundle "switchover" is not running

Comment: So the trick is to register a Leader service and then depend on it. NEVER, repeat NEVER start/stop bundles in these application scenarios. Start/stop , enable, disable are management primitives. Using them makes lots of things hard. Use services to manage these kind of dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Peter, still learning OSGI. I'm happy with this solution and now i have a HA solution for my osgi app. :)